# Edit Paypal module

Tags: paypal-express

I need a help. I want to modify Magento's Paypal Express Checkout module. I want to add some data with the default data sent to Paypal while checkout using Paypal. But I didnot understand where to add data? I searched and find that while I choose paypal to checkout, Paypal uses the following link to proceed to next step:
http://test.com/paypal/express/start
Now I lost. I think the url execute the StartAction of ExpressController of the Paypal Module.But when I want to add some code in the startAction method, the added code is not reflecting on  the page. What should I do? Please help.

Comment: Can you show us your module code that is extending the paypal module so we can help?

Comment: I am not extending the Paypal Module, I am trying to modify the Paypal Module.

Comment: You shouldn't be editing a core module directly as that is not upgrade safe, any changes to the paypal (or any core modules) should be in your own module that overrides/extends the core module. We would also still need to know what code you are trying to we can help you debug and answer your question

Comment: ok. But can you give me a reference example that can extend the core module of Magento? I dont have any experience of extending core magento module.

Comment: Added as an answer although it's a top level overview on how to extend a module.

Comment: ok. I have another question. I am changing on a core module for testing purpose. I just add a die() function within a class, to test the flow of the module. but the die() is not reflecting on the page. Is there any other way to exit the class or script in Magento?

Comment: die(); should work however you would need to also check whether there are any other classes already overriding the one you are trying to edit (Search the whole project for the class name you should find them) alternatively you could use something like xdebug and put a break point in the class too, to find out where it breaks.

Answer (score 0):

To extend a core module you need to create the following folder structure

app/etc/local/Namespace/Module

app/etc/local/Namespace/Module/etc

Within your Namespace/Module/etc folder you will need a config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <namespace_module>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
    </namespace_module>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Then also in app/etc/modules/ you will need a Namespace_Module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <namespace_module>
      <active>true</active>
      <codepool>local</codepool>
    </namespace_module>
  </modules>
</config>
```

Then back in your app/etc/local/Namespace/Module folder you can create your helpers, models and controllers that will override and extend the core ones.

For example if you wanted to override/extend the customer account controller

You would create a controllers/Frontend/Customer/ folder

with an AccountController.php
(you would also have to add this controller as a node to your config.xml)

```
<?php
    require_once Mage::getModuleDir('controllers', 'Mage_Customer').DS.'AccountController.php';

  class Namespace_Module_Frontend_Customer_AccountController
extends Mage_Customer_AccountController
{//here, you extended the core controller with ours

    public function indexAction()
    {
      parent::indexAction();
      //you can always use default functionality
    }
}
```